# Problema al cambiar fondo de un LinearLayout luego de agregar un intersitial Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

He creado cuatro botones con **LinearLayout**, mi usuario debe seleccionar uno, cuando no están seleccionados tienen un fondo gris y cuando se hace click sobre uno su fondo pasa a rojo y el que estaba seleccionado previamente pasa a gris.

Todo funciona bien, pero tras agregar el intersitial de publicidad mis botones solo cambian de color una vez, luego no realizan el cambio del background, pero si sigue funcionando la obtención del valor.

*Si evito cargar el intersitial todo vuelve a funcionar con normalidad.*

Estoy cargando el intersitial en el inicio de mi activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculadora_requerimientos)
    val vibratorService = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as 
Vibrator
    val cfg = Config(baseContext)
    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = getString(R.string.admob_intersitial)
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

Luego, en otro botón que realiza un cambio de intent muestro mi intersitial

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
    mInterstitialAd.show()
} else {
    startActivity(intent)
}

mInterstitialAd.adListener = object: AdListener() {
    override fun onAdLoaded() {
    }

override fun onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode: Int) {
    startActivity(intent)
    }

override fun onAdClosed() {
     startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Como estoy cambiando el background; Luego del llamado de otras funciones para comprobar y modificar la selección anterior para evitar cambiar el fondo de los cuatro botones y sólo cambiar uno con el fin de mejorar el rendimiento, el cambio del background se resume en esto:

```
if ( sedentaria.background.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx,R.drawable.bg_rectangle_no_selected)!!.constantState)
               sedentaria.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.bg_rectangle_selected, null)
```

**¿Por que el intersitial está afectando a mi cambio de background una ves que se ha cargado?**

He pensado que quizá el background si se estaba cargando, sólo que estaba quedando solapado bajo una capa y por eso no se apreciaba el color, pero he intentado agregar:

```
.bringToFront()
```

y el resultado no ha sido el esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Para debuggear vistas cargadas en tiempo de ejecución utiliza esta herramienta de Android Studio. En la barra del IDE mientras tienes la app lanzada desde el ide, dale a **tools > Layout Insepector o doble shift y escribe Layout Inspector**. Allí puedes observar el layout que quieres debugger de tu móvil o emulador.

Comment: Pero tengo entendido que ese debuger no permite ver los recursos de fondos asignados ¿O si?

Comment: Si que permite ver, échale un ojo a documentación : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: Finalmente el error no era de layout, era la inicialización de la publicidad. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido identificar el problema, tenia *MobileAds.initialize()* en un activity principal (activity padre de donde surgía el error con el layout) y previo a eso tenia un splashscreen. Por algún motivo, a pesar que *MobileAds.initialize()* se cargaba un activity antes, este estaba dando conflicto.
Lo he cargado en el splash (el primer activity que lanza mi APP) y todo ha funcionado de maravilla.